# Can any string represent "backspace" in turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle as t
def erase():
     if t.xcor() > -300:
          t.goto(t.xcor()-5,t.ycor())
     else:
          prevline()
     t.color("white")
     t.begin_fill()
     box()
     t.end_fill()
     t.color("black")
def prevline():
     t.goto(300,t.ycor()+10)

t.Screen().onkey(erase,"_")
```

> What would replace the "_" in the above code that would represent the backspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `'BackSpace'` is the tkinter keysym you're looking for.

I'd write your example code something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def erase():
    if turtle.xcor() > -300:
        turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() - 5)
    else:
        prevline()

    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    box()
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.color('black')

def prevline():
    turtle.goto(300, turtle.ycor() + 10)

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(erase, 'BackSpace')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Though doing a white out of a character is likely to be unsatisfactory.  I'd look into doing an `undo()` or some other similar approach.